# why doesn't pandas execute sql query?

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

why doesn't pandas execute sql query?

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

# load data
df = pd.read_csv('CurriculumAuditReport.csv')

# strip whitespace from headers
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

con = sqlite3.connect("sans.db")

# drop data into database
df.to_sql("MyTable", con, if_exists='replace')

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Count (Department) FROM MyTable WHERE `CompletedTraining` LIKE 'Incomplete' GROUP BY Department', con)
print(df)


con.close()
```

the query produces the result i want just fine in DB browser for SQLite

```
the output 
    C:\sans>C:\python34\python test2.py
  File "test2.py", line 15
    df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Count (Department) FROM MyTable WHERE 
`CompletedTraining` LIKE 'Incomplete' GROUP BY Department', con)


                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

my output should have 11 rows

Comment: The first thing to mention is that there is no point using LIKE without a wildcard, just use equals. Or add a wildcard(s) as appropriate.

Comment: what are you trying to count?

Comment: try using `\'Incomplete\'` instead in your code, hope that'll work.

Comment: so what should i use?

Comment: \'Incomplete\' may have done the trick, still need more editing!

Answer (score 4):

You have an issue with quoting - try this:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT Department, count(*) as cnt FROM MyTable WHERE CompletedTraining = 'Incomplete' GROUP BY Department", con)
```

You can also use the following technique:

```
qry = """
SELECT department, count(*) as cnt
FROM MyTable
WHERE CompletedTraining = 'Incomplete'
GROUP BY department
"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, con)
```

Comment: thank you, i was able to get it working, but using \'Incomplete\'

Comment: @davidjbeiler, this is a little bit unusual way of counting in SQL... What do you want to count?

Comment: counting all the 'incomplete' rows in my table/csv but i need to count per department and group by department

Comment: that gives me the total count, not count per department

Comment: @davidjbeiler, yeah, now it should show you all the departments (where `CompletedTraining = 'Incomplete'`) together with the corresponding number of rows...

Comment: C:\python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:1201: UserWarning: The spaces in these column names will not be changed. In pandas versions < 0.14, spaces were converted to underscores.
  chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
{"Department":{"0":"AQPSD","1":"ASD","2":"CO","3":"ECARS","4":"ED","5":"EO","6":"ISD","7":"MSCD","8":"OIS","9":"RD","10":"TTD"},"count(*)":{"0":6,"1":8,"2":2,"3":3,"4":6,"5":4,"6":4,"7":5,"8":1,"9":2,"10":4}}

Comment: any chance i can merge the count with the department name? so AQPSD:0, ASD:8 ect?

Comment: @davidjbeiler, when do you get this error? are you trying to write to SQL?

Comment: no error, its just two separate groups i want department and count in one group

Comment: @davidjbeiler, sorry, i don't understand. I think your question about "pandas sql query" has been answered. Could you open a new question and explain there what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean saying `i want department and count in one group`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015114/how-can-i-merge-two-columns-into-one-final-output-python-sqlite